# How to search ignoring spaces between words?

Tags: mysql, json, search, autocomplete

I want search names using my search module with ignoring white spaces .

Ex: if i want to search a name like "A B Zilva"

i want to disply the results on dropdown even if i type the name like "AB Zilva".

currently search without space is not working

```
   $db = JFactory::getDbo();
$searchp=$_GET["term"];
$searchp = str_replace(' ','%%', trim($searchp));
//$searchp= preg_split('/ /', $searchp);
$query = $db -> getQuery(true);

 $query="SELECT * FROM content where title like '%".$searchp."%'AND categories_id=82 order by title ASC ";
$db -> setQuery($query);
// Load the results as a list of associated arrays.
$results = $db -> loadAssocList();
$json=array();
foreach ($results as $json_result) {
    $json[] = array('value' => $json_result["title"], 'label' => $json_result["title"]);
}
```

Please advice .

**update :**

```
jQuery.extend( jQuery.ui.autocomplete.prototype, {
              _renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
                  var term = this.element.val(),
                      regex = new RegExp( '(' + term + ')', 'gi' );
                  html = item.label.replace( regex , "<b>$&</b>" );
                  return jQuery( "<li></li>" )
                      .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                      .append( jQuery("<a></a>").html(html) )
                      .appendTo( ul );
              }
          });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that when you replace space with `%%`, you get a search like:

```
WHERE title like '%AB%%Zilva%'
```

but this won't match when the title is `A B Zilva`. You need to remove spaces from both the search string and the column in the database. Do it like this:

```
$searchp = str_replace(' ', '', $searchp);
```

and then change the SQL to:

```
WHERE REPLACE(title, ' ', '') LIKE '%$searchp%'
```

For the Javascript highlighting, I think you need to do this:

```
var term = this.element.val().replace(/ /g, '').replace(/.(?=.)/g, '$& *'),
```

This will create a regular expression that allows for spaces between any of the characters in the search string.

Comment: thanks @Barmar , it works, can you check the bottom of my question , where i placed a jquery code. which i used to highlight the word which type. but after the change which i have done as you said , now that highligting part not working. is the code affect to that one as well . please advice